# Regex - match all that don't have /

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a reg expression that would match this kind of sites:

```
[1] www.content.com/nice-page/ending (-page is the constant element)
```

But not these:

```
[2] www.content.com/nice-page/ending/extraline
[3] www.content.com/nice-page/ending/another/line
```

So far I've come up with this:

```
^(http|https):\/\/www.content.com\/[^\/]+-page\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+.*$
```

But it's picking up all 3 types of urls. Maybe a solution would be to match only those urls that don't have a forward slash after -page/ part, but I don't know how to implement that.

Comment: Your regular expression has `.*` at the end, which should match almost everything.

Comment: `+.*` at end of expression will match with any symbol in any number

Comment: So depending on what exactly you're searching... `^[^\/]+(\/[^\/]+){2}$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use :

```
^((http|https):\/\/)?www.content.com\/[^\/]+-page\/[^\/]+$
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/yhqRk3/1) as an example.

And as a more generic regex :

```
^(?:https?:\/\/)?([^\/]+)(\/[^\/]+){0,2}\/?$
```

It maches basically any site with at most 2 subfolders.

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/yhqRk3/3) with more examples.

Comment: `(http|https)` can be replaced by `https?`

Comment: @pbanek you thank people here by accepting and\or upvoting